# Решение проблемы с врагом

Tags: c#, unity3d, искусственный-интеллект

В коде противника есть атака и охрана зоны.

Первая проблема: я не смог внести метод Run в Update.

Вторая - в повороте противника:

```
   float direction = player.transform.position.x - transform.position.x;
   sprite.flipX = direction < 0.0f;
```

То есть противник сначала стоит 1 секунду, после переворачивается на другую сторону, и ходит уже только так. Помогите мне пожалуйста, ибо я много пытался, но так и не пришел к верному написанию кода. Вот сам весь код:

```
public Transform start;

public Transform end;

private SpriteRenderer sprite;

public float arriveTime = 3f;

GameObject player;

const float speedMove = 3.5f;


void Start()
{
    player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
}


void Awake() {
    sprite = GetComponentInChildren <SpriteRenderer> ();
}

void Update()
{
        float direction = player.transform.position.x - transform.position.x;
        sprite.flipX = direction < 0.0f;

 if (Mathf.Abs (direction) < 10) {
     Vector3 pos = transform.position;
     pos.x += Mathf.Sign (direction) * speedMove * Time.deltaTime;
     transform.position = pos;
    }
}


void Run() {
    Vector3 direction = transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(start.position, end.position, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time/arriveTime, 1f));
    sprite.flipX = direction.x < 0.0f;
}
```